# What can I do when bind: adress already in use?

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

When I want to run my network with hyperledger fabric v. 2 and couchdb I get following error for all couchdb and ppeers:

```
WARNING: Host is already in use by another container

ERROR: for ca_peerOrg1  Cannot start service ca0: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint ca_peerOrg1 (e1ebe2f0cbdbddf0a1873a3db798e21ecd9aa5bac1944eb522bddaedabc87eba): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:7054: bind: address already in use
Creating ca_peerOrg2          ... error
```

What I have done so far, but wasn't helping:

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
```

Then I wanted to stop docker compose, by follwoing command:

```
docker-compose stop
```

But I got some errors, and actually I installed docker compose before.

Then I removed the images and installed them again with the commands:

I am always working in the same project. Just starting it sometimes again, to solve some errors.
I do not understand, how I can all bring down and up again.

For starting my network I use following command:

```
sudo ./start_Network.sh
```

If I want to use `sudo ./start_Network.sh down` is not working.

What can I do to solve my errors?

Comment: Publish your docker-compose yaml file. Also refer to the following link to check if there is a process using port `7054`. [pid-using-a-specific-port](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106561/finding-the-pid-of-the-process-using-a-specific-port)

Comment: which docker-compose yaml file? I have docker-compose-ca.yaml; docker-compose-cli.yaml; docker-compose-couch.yaml; docker-compose-couch-org3.yaml. Thank you!

Comment: `docker ps -aq | xargs docker kill` and then do `docker ps -aq | xargs docker rm` to kill and then delete all docker cotainers

Comment: and to find which processes or containers listen on a port, you can do `netstat -nlop | grep <port number>` as root

Comment: @yacovm thank you. When I run `docker ps -aq | xargs docker kill` I get the error: _Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container_  And after the command `docker ps -aq | xargs docker rm` it says: _you cannot remove a running container._  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this is odd, maybe try to run it as root?

Comment: I also tried it as root, but I get the sam errors :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227301/discussion-between-yacovm-and-kate).